# Usar acentos no comando cout

Tags: c++

Boa tarde.
Eu sei que o c++ usa outra forma de asci, então não existem acentos por exemplo, então eu me deparo com problemas como:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "é ó ê A ç";
}
```

Retorna:

```
Ú ¾ Û A þ
```

Existe alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

Comment: Pesquise por locale. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/

Comment: Achei a solução, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use este comando aqui:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
```

se der erro falando que a função não foi declarada, da `include` na biblioteca `locale`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8");
    cout << "Olá Mundo!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Poderia dar uma explicação de como o código funciona e o encaixar no exemplo do AP

Comment: Coloque uma explicação de como o código funciona, pois essa resposta sera lida futuramente por pessoas de todos os graus de conhecimento e uma explicação facilitaria a compreensão do que esta sendo feito para os iniciantes.

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde galera, eu fiz desta forma, e deu certinho.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]